# how find my login for Red Hat linux?

Tags: linux, redhat

I have installed Linux Red Hat v.5 update 6 on WMware. During installation where were no dialog to put login. But the installation finished it require to type login. How can I know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation process will have prompted you to enter a password for the root account. At first log in you can use the username *root* and whatever password you used during installation. Then you can use *useradd* or a GUI (or scripts or whatever you like to use) to make more user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Linux will prompt for root password while installation if you used normal distro. Please try to login with root and the given password , then you can create new user from shell or GUI ( if you installed GUI packages)